# Detect data within csv column with python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have this following csv and it looks like this:

[image]

I want to detect if there is any cells that are more than 1.25 in values.

I have tried using this code but it seems wrong. Any ideas? (I use loop because it's more than 1 csv)

```
dflist = []
for i, file in enumerate(flist):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = [0,1,3,4])
    dflist.append(df)
    if df.iloc[:,45:52].values.flatten()[i] >= 1.2:
        print([i],'Hard Landing')
    else:
        print([i],'Normal Flight')
```

Comment: kindly share data, not pics. use this as a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use df.values function of pandas. It returns a numpyarray.

```
    x = df.values
    w = list(map(float,x))
    y = w[w>1.25]
    if y.size != 0:
      print("Greater Value Exist")
```

Comment: i got an error, 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: Convert the list to float. I have updated the answer.